# iOS app Crashes on Start Up

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I developed an application with Xamarin studio. It runs completely fine with the iPhoneSimulator. I was able to run Ad-Hoc | Iphone and it compiles and actually saves the IPA directly to my phone. When I click the app it launches the load screen and crashes within 1 second.

I've tried to install command line tools for my OSX which is 10.9.

I'm all out of ideas, any help would be great.

```
Warning MT5303: Native linking warning: warning: can't parse dwarf compilation unit info in /Users/test/Google Drive/FernSoftware Mobile App/Hello/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Hello.exe.armv7.o (MT5303) 

Warning MT5303: Native linking warning: warning: can't parse dwarf compilation unit info in /Users/test/Google Drive/FernSoftware Mobile App/Hello/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Data.dll.armv7.o (MT5303)
```

no errors but many warnings similar to that.

```
Jun 20 15:25:59  com.apple.debugserver-199[2466] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [09a2/0303]: error: ::ptrace (request = PT_THUPDATE, pid = 0x09a3, tid = 0x2503, signal = -1) err = Invalid argument (0x00000016)
Jun 20 15:25:59  com.apple.debugserver-199[2466] <Warning>: 2 +0.036680 sec [09a2/1303]: error: ::read ( 5, 0x2fe809fc, 18446744069414585344 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Jun 20 15:25:59  com.apple.debugserver-199[2463] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [099f/0303]: error: ::read ( 5, 0x2fd7cebc, 1024 ) => 0 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Jun 20 15:25:59  mobile_installation_proxy[2461] <Error>: main: Could not receive request from host.
Jun 20 15:25:59  mobile_installation_proxy[2464] <Error>: main: Could not receive request from host.
Jun 20 15:25:59  kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[2467] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Jun 20 15:25:59  kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[2467] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/6C7A90BA-B71E-41F5-BAA1-85B0202BA07F (sandbox)
Jun 20 15:25:59  FaaSBank[2467] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.FaaSBank.FernSoftware [FaaSBank] (793.00)
Jun 20 15:26:00  com.apple.launchd[1] <Error>: (UIKitApplication:com.FaaSBank.FernSoftware[0x1e67]) Exited with code: 1
Jun 20 15:26:00  com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.FaaSBank.FernSoftware[0x1e67]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483647 seconds
Jun 20 15:26:00  backboardd[53] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.FaaSBank.FernSoftware[0x1e67]' exited abnormally with exit status 1
```

The device log is huge but i think these are the important pars

iOS device log 
http://pastebin.com/PDjj0aHJ

Comment: Could you provide more details? Error codes/crash reports/etc

Comment: Given the lovely documented code and detailed explanations of how it works that you've so thoughtfully provided, we're all 100% confident in suggesting this following solution: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: What is your linker set to? Did you actually debug and step through the code? Are you getting a possible null reference exception in one of your startup methods?

Comment: @valdetero my linker is set to SDK assemblies only, it worked with simulator so i would assume the code is fine.

Comment: What if you turn linking off?

Comment: @valdetero same result =(

Comment: added device log if that's of any help

Comment: I usually get these kinds of errors (installing correctly but crashing some little time after start-up) when I don't code-sign the app properly - either I use ad-hoc certificate for debug, or don't list the device in the ad-hoc provisioning profile. Couldn't this happen to you, too?

Answer (score 1):

Go through this, It' would be help you :

1. Architecture settings (armv6, armv7, armv7s) and also check your deployment version setting.
2. Set your Code Signing properly (Build Settings --> Code Signing)
3. Set/Check proper Deployment Target
4. Set/Check your Search Paths, if any. Check your other linker flags.

I think, might be possible your application run perfectly.